# Why do protocol implementations not derive from the protocol class?

Tags: python-3.x

Most examples (including [the one in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#defining-a-protocol)) of using `Protocol` go something like this:

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):

    def do_something(self):
        """
        this should be doing something
        """


class ProtocolImplementation:

    def do_something(self):
        print("I am actually doing something.")


def consume_my_protocol(arg: MyProtocol):
    arg.do_something()
```

Being more used to the OOP features of languages such as Java and C# and having used `ABC` a bit in Python, I am tempted to write the second class like this:

```
class ProtocolImplementation(MyProtocol):

    def do_something(self):
        print("I am actually doing something.")
```

Although both ways seem to work exactly the same and neither generates any warnings, I believe that the second way makes it clear that the `ProtocolImplementation` class actually implements the protocol, without having to infer that it does from the usage of the class.

Is there a good reason not to do it the second way?

Will people laugh at me if I do?

Comment: If you inherit MyProtocol, what's the point of making a Protocol? You only need that in cases where you want to describe the relationship of the interfaces _without_ inheritance.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure, but then you don't really **need** to use inheritance in many cases in Python, just pass in objects with the correctly defined methods and it will work as expected. My example will work just fine if I remove all the inheritance including the one from Protocol and the type hint. But it will be less clear, in my opinion.

Comment: Right, but the whole point of that feature is _static_ duck types, i.e. duck typing you can use in and check against type annotations. _"In this PEP we specify static and runtime semantics of protocol classes that will provide a support for_ structural _subtyping (static duck typing)."_

Comment: Is your question answered by the [Explicitly declaring implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation) section of that PEP?

Comment: @Brian indeed it does... feel free to post and quote it in your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Because that's the *entire point of a `Protocol`, to provide a form of structural typing to augment the class-based, nominal typing for Python type annotations. It's explained in the PEP you link